# Is BBS+ 1. a multi-messages signing protocol or 2. a group signature signed by a member of a group anonymously?

Tags: signature, diffie-hellman, zero-knowledge-proofs, pairings

There's no doubt that the BBS Signature was born from this classic [Short Group Signature](https://crypto.stanford.edu/%7Edabo/pubs/papers/groupsigs.pdf) paper in 2004. It's capable of Zero-knowledge.
In the paper, section 5, it describes how a member of a group, can sign a message, without revealing which member signed it. But, this *group signature* can be verified that it was signed by a member of a group (anonymously) through a group public key $gpk$.

However, later, there are some works improving BBS into BBS+. It was first modified and named in [Constant-Size Dynamic k-TAA](http://web.cs.iastate.edu/%7Ewzhang/teach-552/ReadingList/552-14.pdf) by Au et al. BBS+ was touched again in [Anonymous Attestation Using the Strong Diffie Hellman Assumption Revisited](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/306347781_Anonymous_Attestation_Using_the_Strong_Diffie_Hellman_Assumption_Revisited). Nevertheless, in those two papers mentioned above, it seems the BBS+ scheme is *a multi-messages signing protocol*. It takes messages $m_1, m_2, m_3,..., m_L$ and produces a single signature $\sigma$.
It can create a proof of knowledge $SPK$ on top of signature $\sigma$, with some messages $m_i$ revealed.

Yet, in work on [Enhanced Privacy ID from Bilinear Pairing](https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/095.pdf) by intel, it seems their BBS+ scheme becomes as a member of a group signing the message anonymously, same as [Short Group Signature](https://crypto.stanford.edu/%7Edabo/pubs/papers/groupsigs.pdf) paper in 2004.

Therefore, I'm confused about BBS+ protocol. Whether it is

1. a multi-message $m_1, m_2, m_3,..., m_L$ signing protocol producing a single signature $\sigma$ with signature proof of knowledge $SPK$

or

2. a group signature signed by a member of a group anonymously using a group public key $gpk$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always used it as #1. Hyperledger Ursa has an implementation in Rust
(see https://github.com/hyperledger/ursa/tree/master/libzmix/bbs).

However, it is a type of group signature which allows the type of signing of multiple messages.

When someone says to me group signature I immediately think your #2. If we look at a paper written by David Chaum (https://chaum.com/publications/Group_Signatures.pdf), He mentions

group signatures are a "generalization" of the credential/ membership authentication schemes, in which one person proves that he belongs to a certain group.

So in effect, the proof being made is proving the messages belong to the signature and the signature allows for a proof of knowledge to be made.
It's a different use of a crypto primitive.

Hope this helps